# Как настроить Stylelint для scss

Tags: css, scss, eslint

Не могу подобрать свойства для stylelint что бы были отступы в подобном формате:

```
.s{

  .f{
      width:2px;
   }

  .d{
     width:2px;
    }

}
```

При использовании свойства: `"block-closing-brace-empty-line-before": "always-multi-line"`

Строится подобная структура:

```
.s{

  .f{
      width:2px;

   }

  .d{
     width:2px;

    }

}
```

Добавляются отступы после свойства

Comment: Если еще актуально: `"block-closing-brace-newline-before": null` - оно? :)

Comment: @yar85 Нет( Не работает

Comment: Ну так и цель была в том чтобы не работало, судя по вопросу. И это отключает правило, то есть `\n` перед `}` уже не требуется.

Comment: О, блин, я не ту строчку из конфига скопировал - это для возможности блоков в одну строку, не то)) Вот эту надо было скопировать: `"block-closing-brace-empty-line-before": null` (в общем-то нетрудно догадаться, как отключается правило. Если нужно не отключать, а обратить: `"never"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правило конфига [`block-closing-brace-empty-line-before`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/block-closing-brace-empty-line-before) может принимать следующие значения:

- `null` - отключить проверку правила (и исправления по нему, если доступны)
- `"always-multi-line"` - требовать пустую строку перед `}` только в многострочных блоках
- `"never"` - требовать отсутствие пустой строки перед `}` во всех случаях

---

Дополнительно есть опция `except`, принимающая массив исключений.
В данный момент, поддерживается только одно исключение `"after-closing-brace"` - оно инвертирует правило в случае двух `}` подряд. То есть:

- при `["always-multi-line", { "except": ["after-closing-brace"] }]` ожидается

  ```
  .foo {
    .bar {
      margin: 0;

    }
  }
  ```
- при `["never", { "except": ["after-closing-brace"] }]` ожидается

  ```
  .foo {
    .bar {
      margin: 0;
    }

  }
  ```

Comment: Ну и еще должны поддерживаться общие для всех правил доп. опции: `message`, `severity`, `reportDisables`...

Comment: Работает только для функций АТ ( @media ) при исключении: ```["never", { "except": ["after-closing-brace"] }]```

Comment: @Locker, ну значит баг, очевидно жеж...

Comment: Уже писали об этом в гит, разработчики говорят что изменять логику не будут

Comment: @Locker, у Stylelint всегда были сложные отношения с SASS, к сожалению. Это вообще линтер для CSS изначально, т.е. думаю что полноценная поддержка препроцессоров возможна только если переписать линтер с нуля (заложив их поддержку в его основу, а не "прикручивая сбоку" фиксами парсера). Такие правила при использовании SASS лучше просто отключать... по факту, я ни разу не видел их включенными в проектах над которыми работал.